# Youtube api (c#) strange error

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I have been puzzling with this problem for 3 days now but i cant figure out any solution. Excuse me if this is no the place to ask that kind of question. But believe me i have not other alternatives.

I have an application where the user can upload the video and then via youtube api uploads them to a certain youtube channel. This app is hosted in an amazon host. Great so far!

Due to ssl reasons i have to deploy this app in a different host. So i make an exact instance of my host. But the problem is that i get this error when i try to upload via youtube api :

**The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**

All my deploy files are copy-paste from one host to another. The structure and configuration of the host is the exact same (as i mentioned before it is an exact instance).

I would be grateful if some of you had any ideas. Again sorry if this is the wrong place to post this question.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I updated the youtube dll's with the current version and i have this message:

**Invalid Credentials**

The weird thing is that i get this message only in a specific youtube/google account. In every other account i try the video gets uploaded correctly.

Maybe is something wrong with the account?

Answer (score 0):

"The HTTP body of the 403 Forbidden response should contain an XML
description of the error along with it's specific cause."

Assuming you are using HttpWebRequest. Use the [WebException.Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) to get the body and log the xml response.

```
try
{
    var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("youtube api");
    using (var resp = http.GetResponse())
    {
        //Handle api response
    }
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    if (we.Response == null)
        throw; //Rethrow because it doesn't have a body.

    var resp = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
    if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        throw; //We are only handling forbidden, rethrow other statuses.

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
        //Log xml here
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i figured what the problem was about.

I tried to manually login to youtube from the amazon server and to my suprise it requested a captcha input.

After entering the captcha, everything worked great!