# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden in Youtube api

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I am using Youtube API to upload videos. Its working fine in my local machine but it throws below exception after I implemented my code into server.

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

I have mentioned username, developerkey, password correctly. Could you please any one help me that where I am wrong?

Comment: Can you check the description of the error? You can use "WebExecption.Response" as mentioned here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959985/youtube-api-c-strange-error

Comment: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined error has occurred after I used the code mentioned in above link.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using along with the URI?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 403 responses can be associated with a number of different errors, and taking a look at the actual response HTTP body (or the serialized version of it reported in the exception.Response property) is the only way of determining the exact cause.

A very common cause of 403s when performing uploads are quota errors, though. Here are more details: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota.html

Comment: I couldn't able to get the video feeds also. So what would be wrong?

Comment: I'll repeat: "HTTP 403 responses can be associated with a number of different errors, and taking a look at the actual response HTTP body (or the serialized version of it reported in the exception.Response property) is the only way of determining the exact cause."